# glyphicon cheatsheet not shown - Angular 5

Tags: html, angular, glyphicons

I have created an `input` that shows a `glyphicon` and some text (text is not shown in pictures cause it is not relevant).

```
<select class="form-control glyphicon" required>
    <option value="empty"></option>
    <option *ngFor="let car of cars" value="true">&#xe043; {{car.name}}</option>
</select>
```

This code partially  works. It shows correctly what I what to show after selecting the option, but it does not while I visualize the proper option. I attach a photo to explain it better:

[image]

I would like to know if it is possible to show the icon also during the selection of it.

Comment: May they're picking another font and not yours of glyphicons without glyphicon-someicon

Comment: You are right. The font that I am using do not allow me to see them. I have to change it for this 2 inputs